# What does Explore mean here?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have applied for a sales copywriting job. They have asked me to fill up a form where they put this question,

'How do you explore into writing?'

what do they mean by 'explore'? Does it mean research or analysis?

Comment: One thing is clear: they badly need a copy**editor**.

Comment: They've probably left it unclear (open to various interpretations) deliberately. _A bit like a test._

Answer (score 1):

> explore, verb
>
> > travel in or through (an unfamiliar country or area) in order to **learn about or familiarize oneself with it**.

In other words, "How do you **learn more about** and **familiarize yourself** with writing?"